# Add IsDirty-Flag on TextBox with DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have the problem, that I have a existing model object which i can´t extend. The actual problem is a bit more complex, so i try to break it down.

I want to extend a `TextBox` with a dependency property to indicate the text has changed. So i came up with following solution:

```
public class MyTextField : TextBox
{
    public MyTextField()
    {
        this.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(MyTextField_TextChanged);
    }

    private void MyTextField_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsDirty = true;
    }
    public static DependencyProperty IsDirtyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsDirtyProperty",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(MyTextField),
        new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public bool IsDirty
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsDirtyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsDirtyProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<my:MiaTextField Text="{Binding Barcode}" IsDirty="{Binding IsDirty}"/>
```

So if I change the text in the `TextBox`, the `isDirty` Property should change to `true`.
But I got a `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException`: Binding can only set for a "DependencyProperty" of "DependencyObject".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could [override the PropertyMetadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.overridemetadata?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.DependencyProperty.OverrideMetadata);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7) of the TextProperty:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    static MyTextBox()
    {
        TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", IsDirtyUpdateCallback));
    }

    private static void IsDirtyUpdateCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is MyTextBox tb && e.NewValue != e.OldValue && e.Property == TextProperty)
        {
            tb.IsDirty = (string)e.OldValue != (string)e.NewValue;
        }
    }



    public bool IsDirty
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsDirtyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsDirtyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDirtyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsDirty", typeof(bool), typeof(MyTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(true));
}
```

to automatically set your IsDirty :o)  more then one way to rome. But for your proplem thats kinda Shooting small birds with cannons (German proverb)

Comment: first of all big thanks. Unfortunately the binding isn´t working. I have my 
`Textbox` inside a `GridView` bound with a  `ObservableCollection`. The `IsDirtyProperty` -DP is set correctly.

Comment: @Marcel: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: The binding? Your question was about a XamlParseException, wasn't it?

Comment: Thats true, the exception is gone, but now the binding isn´t working

Answer (score 5):

Pass "IsDirty", i.e. the name of the CLR wrapper for the dependency property, to the `DependencyProperty.Register` method:

```
public static DependencyProperty IsDirtyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "IsDirty",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(MyTextField),
    new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

If you are using C#6 / Visual Studio 2015 or later, you could use the `nameof` operator:

```
public static DependencyProperty IsDirtyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(IsDirty),
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(MyTextField),
    new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

Comment: You could add compile time safety and remove the magic string by using `nameof(IsDirty)`

Comment: If you use a recent VisualStudio you get almost all of this via `propdp + TAB + TAB` - a snippet for Dependency Properties usable insiode your source code. The class must derive from DependencyObject but TextBox does so ok.